# Electron.js | Как скрыть верхние кнопки "закрыть, скрыть, в полный экран"

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, reactjs

занимаюсь разработкой лаунчера для какое какой игры на основе Electron.js и React.js, недавно доделал шаблон сам и приступил к натягиванию на Electron.js, но столкнулся с проблемой, что верхние кнопки, а именно "скрыть, в полный экран, закрыть" очень неподходят моему дизайну. Я в целом планировал что скрою их, поэтому сделал отдельный дизайн для них и вёрстку, но функций не нашёл. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно скрыть такие кнопки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы создаете экземпляр `BrowserWindow`, укажите в параметрах `frame: 0`.

Например:

```js
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(
{
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
    frame: 0,
    webPreferences:
    {
        nodeIntegration: true
    }
});
```

Возможно следующим вопросом будет: **как перетаскивать окно?**
Ответ:
Для HTML элемента, за который нужно будет перетягивать окно, нужно дать такое css свойство:

```
-webkit-app-region: drag;
```