# Electron JS не работает remote .remote is undefined

Tags: electron

Впервые работаю с Electron.

Как сделать своё верхнее меню (свернуть, закрыть). Везде пишут про remote. Но у меня не работает, и когда импортирую из electron, такой метод не находит.

Comment: меню лучше делать из main-процесса, а не из render

Comment: @nörbörnën но там же нельзя использовать html и css, или из htlm файла можно указать путь до main js? точно, чот не подумал

Comment: верно. но в [электроновском меню](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/menu) не нужен html и css

Comment: @nörbörnën но как сделать тогда красивые кнопки закрытия и свёртывания?

Comment: возможно мы говорим о разных вещах. я называю "меню" [вот такую штуку](https://s3.amazonaws.com/coursetro/posts/content_images/4-1511885562045.png). а вы, наверное, хотите заменить весь menu bar

Comment: на ваш вопрос ответили [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63613584/4496422)

Comment: @nörbörnën да, я везде смотрел, и это тоже прописывал. Но суть в том, что когда я прописываю require('electron').remote, там remote попросту нету, и в доках тоже его нет https://www.electronjs.org/docs

Comment: оказывается, в электроне всё переиграли. [история вопроса](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21408#issue-533651777), сообщение о [Breaking Changes](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/breaking-changes#removed-remote-module) с рекомендациями

Comment: обратите внимание, в описании библиотеки @electron/remote сказано почти то же, что я писал вам в первом сообщении Warning! This module has many subtle pitfalls. There is almost always a better way to accomplish your task than using this module. For example, ipcRenderer.invoke can serve many common use cases.

Comment: @nörbörnën Тут ещё проблемка, у меня даже, если указана enableRemoteModule: true. Мне пишет: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: @nörbörnën всё получилось, если в webPreferences сделать вот так:
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      nativeWindowOpen: true,

Но теперь новая проблема у меня не работает перетаскивание окна :(

Comment: вы могли бы сами воспользоваться поиском по сайту и найти https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1260888/2659

Comment: @nörbörnën Я очень извиняюсь, что вас тревожу. Но я уже прописывал это css свойство   -webkit-app-region: drag; Но это не работает да и ещё у меня hover эффекты переставали работать я написал  -webkit-app-region(вот это ->)-(<-): drag; и hover работал, но перетаскивание не было.. Сейчас задолбался и решил добавить jquery(хотя очень не хотел) и взял код с сайта в итоге перетаскивание работает.. Ещё раз сорян

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В разделе [Breaking Changes](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/breaking-changes#removed-remote-module) написано:

```
Removed: remote module
The remote module was deprecated in Electron 12,
and will be removed in Electron 14.
It is replaced by the @electron/remote module.

// Deprecated in Electron 12:
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote

// Replace with:
const { BrowserWindow } = require('@electron/remote')

// In the main process:
require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()
```

Так что я установил модуль [@electron/remote](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@electron/remote) и у меня получилось всё же сделать закрытие окна по кастомной кнопке.

Вот:

```js
const remote = require('@electron/remote');

const wind = remote.getCurrentWindow();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  $('.btn-close').click(() => {
    wind.close();
  });
  $('.btn-minimize').click(() => {
    wind.minimize();
  });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  var wX = 0;
  var wY = 0;
  var dragging = false;
  $('.launcher').mousedown(function (e) {
    dragging = true;
    wX = e.pageX;
    wY = e.pageY;
  });

  $(window).mousemove(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    if (dragging) {
      var xLoc = e.screenX - wX;
      var yLoc = e.screenY - wY;

      try {
        window.moveTo(xLoc, yLoc);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  });

  $(window).mouseup(function () {
    dragging = false;
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/normalize.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-DyZ88mC6Up2uqS4h/KRgHuoeGwBcD4Ng9SiP4dIRy0EXTlnuz47vAwmeGwVChigm"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="launcher">
      <div class="left">sxa</div>
      <div class="right">
        <div class="header">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu_item">Игровые сервера</li>
            <li class="menu_item">Сообщества</li>
          </ul>
          <div class="control-btns">
            <div class="btn-minimize">Свернуть</div>
            <div class="btn-close"><i class="fas fa-window-close"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
      onload="window.$ = window.jQuery = module.exports;"
    ></script>
    <script src="src/js/common.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Код в main.js:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
require('@electron/remote/main').initialize();
const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain;

function createWindow() {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 900,
    height: 600,
    resizable: false,
    title: 'FUNNIX5 Launcher',
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      nativeWindowOpen: true,
    },
  });
  win.loadFile('index.html');
  win.webContents.openDevTools();
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit();
});
```